# Firefox 29 type="number" with CSS :focus broken

Tags: html, css, firefox, input, numbers

Since Firefox implemented `type=number` my forms that were using this along with CSS `:focus` seem to have utterly broken. Getting the input to actually focus requires clicking in, out, and back in again. Even then, the value of that input can't be read by jQuery.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BUvdq/3/

Is there any way around this while preserving the ability to bring up a numerical keyboard in Android and iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears `:focus{position:relative;}` was causing this. Removed and focusing works.

Comment: Thank you, you just saved me some hassle. I hope Firefox fixes this issue soon